# How to prove that a pair of numbers is a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

I will define the set $K = \left\{ ak + bh | k,h \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$, and a and b are some integers.  Can I say that $K$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$?  I think I can because

1. $K$ is closed.  i.e. $ak + bh$ will always be an integer, and thus, it will be in $\mathbb{Z}$.
2. $K$ is associative.  i.e. $(ak_1 + bh_1) + ak_2 + bh_2 = ak_1 + bh_1 + (ak_2 + bh_2)$, where $k_i$ and $h_i$ are integers.  (I'm not sure if this is an associative proof, please correct me if I am wrong)
3. $K$ has the identity element. i.e. $(ak + bh) + e = ak + bh$, $e$ would be zero.
4. $K$ has an inverse for each element. i.e $(ak + bh) + inverse = 0$, and the inverse would be $a(-k) + b(-h)$.

Is my thinking valid?  Please correct me if I am wrong, or if you have any suggestions.

Comment: In (3) you haven't shown how to get 0 in the format of elements of $K$. (the result you are quoting is correct. Your proof needs this details)

Comment: In (1), it is not enough to state the obvious fact that $ak+bh\in\mathbb Z$. You must show that the sum of two elements in $K$ is also in $K$.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Also, do you guys know if (2) correct?

Comment: The way you've written (2) is incorrect. It is normally enough to say $K$ inherits associativity from $\mathbb{Z}$, but to be explicit you need to use three elements of $K$, say $p,q,r$ and then $(p+q)+r=p+(q+r)$ by associativity of addition in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thank you, this helped greatly.

Answer (score 3):

1) No. One needs to show that the product (so, here, addition) of any two elements of $K$ is in $K$.

2) No. One usually says that associativity in $K$ is inherited from $\Bbb Z$, since, indeed, all elements of $K$ are integers and the set of integers under addition is associative.

3) Correct!

4) Again, correct. Well done!

---

An alternative approach would be to use either one of the one- or two-step subgroup lemmas.  Their statements and proofs are readily found online.